# how to enter « » on windows keyboard

Tags: windows, eclipse, model, keyboard, uml

I am not even sure how to ask this, because I do not even know what these symbols are called.

What are these symbols: « and »

And how to I type them in?  I am working with Eclipse and UML (with UML Lab) and there are some places where I need to type them, but I am not sure how.

I have a standard U.S. Keyboard.

I tried searches but the search engines won't recognize the symbol and I don't even know what it is called.

These are not < and >.  It's like two together:  << and >>, but not, they are: « and »

Answer (score 3):

These characters are called [Guillemets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet).

If you are using UMLLab and the Xpand editor, you can enter these by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> (on some keyboard layouts you may have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> too)

[Xpand documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xpand.doc/help/ch01s06.html)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)  you may see that these characters have the extended codes of 174 and 175.

This means that you can type them with  Left Alt+174 and Left Alt+175

When typing 174 or 175, in my case, I am using the numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There are no symbols or characters like that in the keyboard. As you have said, it is only a greater than > and a less than symbol <

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can always create new templates containing arbitrary strings in the Workspace preferences. Those are then available using the normal code completion (Ctrl+Space).